# Not able to access passed list of words in get url

Tags: python, flask, nltk, flask-restful, spacy

How to pass a `list` from postman and how to access more than one attribute

```
@api.route('/Spacy/<input>/<texts>')
class Spacy(Resource):
    if input == pos:
        def get(self, input):
            '''
            Returns part-of speech.
            '''
            doc = nlp(texts)
            return [(word.text, word.lemma_, word.pos_) for word in doc]
    elif input == verb:
        def get(self, input):
            '''
            Returns verbs and the stemmed verb.
            '''
            doc = nlp(texts)
            return [(word.text, word.lemma_) for word in doc if word.pos_ == "VERB"]
    elif input == synonyms:
        def get(self, input):
            '''
            Returns the synonyms.
            '''
            synonyms = wordnet.synsets(input)
            lemmas = set(chain.from_iterable([word.lemma_names() for word in synonyms]))
            return jsonify([syn.replace("_"," ") for syn in list(lemmas)])
```

i'm passing `/spacy?input=verb,synonyms&text=flower`
how should I accept it and pass through the code

I'm using spacy too

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query parameters to `/spacy?input=verb&input=synonyms&text=flower`. And use `request.args.getlist("input")` to get a list value of `input`.

Comment: Can you give a example, it will be more helpful